# What is the anti derivative of $ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

Tags: calculus

I'm working on a formula just for fun and I need to know what is the antidervative of one function

divided by another like $\displaystyle \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ And then specifically

where $f(x) = |x|$ (absolute value  of $x$) and $g(x) =$ any function, like for my example, $3x^2$

I would greatly appreciate it if you can help me solve this!

Comment: Any function can be written as $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, but not every function has a nice primitive. Take $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$ and $g(x)=1+x^2$, for instance. We know almost everything about $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, but that does not help us in finding $\int\frac{e^{-|x|}}{1+x^2}\,dx$.

Comment: Although there isn't a general solution, per se, you could format this along the lines of integration by parts and get a somewhat simplified solution.

Comment: I would try to come up with a rule for something easier, such as $$\int \frac{f'(x)}{g(x)}dx$$

Answer (score 2):

In general, you won't find a simple soplution in terms of the antiderivative of $f$ and $g$.

In your specific example, you can consider the function $g(x) =  |x| \ln(|x|)$. While the antiderivative of $g$ can easily be computed using integration by parts, the antiderivative of $\frac{|x|}{|x| \ln(|x|)} = \frac{1}{\ln(|x|)}$ is not an elementary function [c.f. [logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function)].

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle I = \int \frac{|x|}{3x^2}dx = \pm \int\frac{x}{3x^2}dx = \pm \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{1}{x}dx = \pm \frac{1}{3}\ln |x|+\mathcal{C}$

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the answers but there is a problem. In my original post I said that I need the antidervative of f(x)/g(x) where specifically f(x)=|u| ( yes the abs of "u" where "u" represents a different function like x^3-1) and g(x) =  any function like 3x^2                              I found that the antiderivative of |u| = u*|u|/2 if it helps but I don't know how to incorporate g(x) (in this case 3x^2) along with it. Ps. I'm not sure how my original post was changed since I am new here